# How to disable cookieless URLs?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, forms-authentication

I upgraded my asp.net application from  mvc2 to mvc4 and moved it from IIS6 to IIS7.
After that I noticed strange urls generated by mvc routing. After some investigation, I found that these urls -  Forms Authentication ticket.

This ticket should be in url, only when it is not possible to use cookies. But I got these tickets in my urls in 70% cases, on different machines(browser Chrome, not sure about other) and even when I'm not logged in. Other users also reported same problems.

So I tried to configure  cookieless in web.config

```
<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" />
```

or

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" />
```

also tried

```
<forms cookieless="UseCookies"
```

But without any success. When I clear all cookies in browser, it helps for small time.

Anybody know how to disable it at all, or how to solve my problem in another way?

Comment: tested on IE. looks like, it appears only I did sign in at least once